# One Fixed background full screen resizable, then add a second image not fixed/or wrapper

Tags: css, background, wrapper

I already applied a background image, full screen and fixed for any resolution:

```
body {

background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Sky_with_puffy_clouds.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;

}
```

However, what I need now is to place another image in the center, which will repeat down (scrollable) and  follow the body if the browser is resized. (the image is [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fcyW3-zf_QU/UJMiLfDY44I/AAAAAAAAAIg/wA9ZVtJ3aLM/s1600/innertest.jpg)).

When I try to add the second image with a comma in the body html, the "no-repeat center center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;...." action from the first image is applied on the new one.

Is there any way to add another image the way I described and keep the original one as it is?

Basically I want to use this image as a wrapper for everything, body etc.

I do apologise, I am quite the newbie and I just started getting acquainted with things.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<p>I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.
   I think your problem solved.</p>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
width:100%;
background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Sky_with_puffy_clouds.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;

}

.main{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:960px;
  background:url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fcyW3-zf_QU/UJMiLfDY44I/AAAAAAAAAIg/wA9ZVtJ3aLM/s1600/innertest.jpg') no-repeat;

}
```